# Trim middlename (to middle initial) if it exists and skip if middlename is null

Tags: sql

```
-- these lines doesn't work
        case 
                when isnull(null,e.middlename) = null then (e.firstname+' '+e.lastname)
                when e.middlename=' ' then (e.firstname+''+e.lastname)
                else (e.firstname +" " +cast(left(e.middlename,1) as varchar)+'. 'e.lastname)
       end as MedTech
--

-- line below works fine but will be null if middlename is null     
,MedTech2 = f.firstname +' '+cast(left(f.middlename,1) as varchar)+'. '+f.lastname
```

It has inner join below

Comment: Please include some sample data in your question.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below - you need to check `null` with `'e.middlename is null'`

```
case when e.middlename is null or e.middlename=' ' then e.firstname+' '+e.lastname
else e.firstname +" " +cast(left(e.middlename,1) as varchar)+'. '+e.lastname
end as MedTech
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work on any SQL99 compatible engine:

```
SELECT firstname || ' ' || coalesce(substring(middlename from 1 for 1) || ' ', '') || lastname
```

Comment: I'd say the opposite, only a few SQL engines support `+` for concatenation. However, it seems like OP is using one of them.

Comment: @jarlh, thanks. fixed to use SQL99 concatenate syntax